# how to move a Google Application Engine based website to Amazon platform?

Tags: google-app-engine

how to move a Google Application Engine based website to Amazon platform?
do i need to recode all of the API?

Comment: What language? What platforms?

Comment: JAVA and what do you mean for platform?

Comment: Pekka probably means what amazon platform are you talking about when you say "Amazon platform" in your question.  Also, to make this a good question, you should talk about which App Engine API's you used, how you access the datastore, why you want to move, how much code you have, what your expected traffic will be, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at AppScale, http://code.google.com/p/appscale/wiki/Deploying_AppScale_1_3_via_EC2

I've never used AppScale, there may be other options, but that is the one I know about.

You'll need to pick a db to replace the DataStore, and there are a bunch of options, like MongoDB, etc.